# ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules\@types\jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, webpack, jasmine

My webpack build started failing out of nowhere with no packages being updated. I assume some minor version update caused this, but can't figure out how to get around it. Does anyone know what to do?

```
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:39:52 
    TS1005: '=' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:39:38 
    TS2371: A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:39:46 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'keyof'.
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.7",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~2.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.1",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "@vaadin/angular2-polymer": "^1.0.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.1",
    "bootstrap-tour": "^0.11.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "icheck": "^1.0.2",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "metismenu": "2.0.2",
    "nestable": "^0.2.0",
    "ng2-modal": "0.0.24",
    "ng2-tag-input": "~0.8.4",
    "pace": "0.0.4",
    "pace-progress": "^1.0.2",
    "primeng": "^1.1.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "~5.1.0",
    "summernote": "^0.8.2",
    "zone.js": "0.7.4",
    "ag-grid": "~8.0.1",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "~8.0.1",
    "ag-grid-ng2": "~8.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.4.1",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.38",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.0.4-rc.2",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.12.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "1.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.8.1",
    "ngc-webpack": "^1.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.1.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.0",
    "parse5": "^3.0.1",
    "protractor": "^4.0.10",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.2.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0", 
    "typedoc": "^0.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.0.10",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "v8-lazy-parse-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.3.0",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "~2.6.1"
  }
```

Comment: Hi there, have you managed to resolve this issue.? I have the same problem

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Looks like your `@types/jasmine` library was upgraded to the latest version since you have the caret symbol:

```
"@types/jasmine": "^2.2.34",
```

The latest version is having issues as this [bug](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/14569) suggests. So try for now by setting the version to 2.5.41 in your package.json :

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41"
}
```

Maybe you have to delete your `node-modules` folder and run `npm install` for a clean installation.

Comment: Thanks! I guess using the ^ is a risky idea seeing how often this seems to happen.

Answer (score 5):

**If you're not using Angular 2, update your TypeScript to 2.1.6 or higher, please. This should help.**

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/214), a more correct solution is to keep TypeScript updated to the latest stable minor version of `2.x` branch, which is `2.1.6` as of now (Feb 12, 2017). The error you have in a build log indicates that you are using an outdated `2.0.10` version. The latest `jasmine` definition file has a new syntax check in `spyOn()` function which is available only for TypeScript `>=2.1.0`. Generally, you should have no serious reason to stick to `2.0.10`, so, please upgrade. However, if there's a backward compatibility issue preventing you from the upgrade, you should fill in the issue form here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues and make the compiler team aware of a bug.

**UPD**: Avoid in your `package.json` lines like these: `"typescript": "2.0.10`, `"typescript": "~2.0.0"`. Instead of `~` you should apply `^` restriction (allows to update minor version numbers, not only hotfixes) like `"typescript": ^2.0.0"`.

Hope that helps. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: How do I upgrade it? This was my first thought yesterday and I googled how to update it and ran the npm commands, but when I ran webpack it still said I was using the older version.

Comment: @Josh, I see that in your `package.json` there is a line `"typescript": "2.0.10"`. Could you please update it to `"typescript": "^2.0.10"` and run `npm update`? Does it help in your case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a proper suggestion. Angular 2.x does *not* have support for TS 2.1.X. Angular 4.x will add that support. If you upgrade to Typescript 2.1.X then you risk having issues with AoT among other things.

Comment: Anyway, the 2.1.x support is planned to be backported into Angular 2.x, so even if it is not the case right now, my answer will be a more correct one in the future. Also, this answer can be helpful in other cases, when you've got a non-Angular2 project.@SoFLy, thank you very much for the comment, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Even with Angular 2+ I had this problem. What solved the problem to me, instead of downgrading Jasmine was updating Typescript.

My steps were:

- Change `package.json` to point to a new version of typescript

  - `"typescript": "~2.0.9"` -> `"typescript": "^2.0.9"`
- Run `npm install`
- After this the error was gone.