# Errors while using Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to learn webpack by following [this tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html).

I am getting 70 errors as below when I run pm start.

```
$ npm start

> angular2-webpack@1.0.0 start /Users/angular-webpak

[at-loader] Using typescript@2.0.10 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from /Users/angular-webpak/src/tsconfig.json.

[at-loader] Checking finished with 70 errors
...

ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:39:52 
    TS1005: '=' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts:48:34 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts:44:38 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/compiler.d.ts:32:38 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/compiler.d.ts:44:32 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/compiler_host.d.ts:20:33 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:342:20 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:344:28 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:346:15 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:348:23 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:350:17 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts:352:25 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts:38:72 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_normalizer.d.ts:40:74 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/i18n/extractor.d.ts:14:33 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/i18n/extractor.d.ts:22:35 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/jit/compiler.d.ts:44:49 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/jit/compiler.d.ts:46:65 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.d.ts:58:104 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts:433:63 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/resource_loader.d.ts:13:23 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts:33:18 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.d.ts:34:46 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
<snipped several similar errors>
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts:24:15 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts:28:16 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
<snipped several similar errors>
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/shared_styles_host.d.ts:11:30 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/shared_styles_host.d.ts:22:30 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/router/src/config.d.ts:307:85 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts:78:99 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts:157:109 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts:227:115 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts:297:89 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/router/src/interfaces.d.ts:367:50 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/router/src/router.d.ts:392:70 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/router/src/router.d.ts:414:59 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@angular/router/src/utils/collection.d.ts:36:79 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:39:38 
    TS2371: A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts:39:46 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'keyof'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:68:60 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts:68:70 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts:40:31 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts:41:26 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts:2:60 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts:3:79 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts:3:89 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in [at-loader] src/app/app.component.ts:8:14 
    TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
ERROR in [at-loader] src/app/app.module.ts:13:14 
    TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    chunk    {0} index.html 299 bytes [entry] [rendered]
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
    chunk    {0} extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename 1.95 kB [entry] [rendered]
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: `rm -rf nodes_modules` then `npm install` then `npm start`

Comment: nope. Did not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fix is here https://github.com/angular/angular.io/pull/3233/commits/8e886fc2710acadd749139c2172519de254b849c

You must modifiy webpack.common.js

Comment: Yes, the issue is with the location of tsconfig.json and webpack.common.js configuration as Irfan Syed and Lamer mentioned. This is correct as the standard location for tsconfig.json is the root directory. Modified web pack.common.js as per the link. It worked fine!
Thank you.

Comment: I had to reverse that pull request for mine to work. Typescript did not use/find the tsconfig. After adding the configFileName option as described in the Typescript docs did it work.

Answer (score 2):

1. Since you're using Angular 2, the only possible solution in your case at th moment is to freeze `@types/jasmine` version to `2.5.41`.

   See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182400/3472184
2. Also, it looks like you have no **ES6** support in `tsconfig.json`.

   See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38212418/3472184 . Pay attention to `lib` and `target` properties.

Comment: With above 68 errors are gone! But, still I am getting:
TS1219: <snip> Set the 'experimen
talDecorators' option to remove this warning.
My tsconfig.json is as follows:
`
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es5", "es2015.promise"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}

`

Answer (score 1):

1. Move the tsconfig.json to `./src folder`. Please see `config/webpack.common.js` line 7:

   ```
   options: {
     configFileName: helpers.root('src', 'tsconfig.json')
   }
   ```
2. change tsconfig.json to:

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es5",
       "module": "commonjs",
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "sourceMap": true,
       "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
       "experimentalDecorators": true,
       "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
       "noImplicitAny": true,
       "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
       "types" : ["node"]
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

@user2995358 for your TS1219:  Set the 'experimen talDecorators' option to remove this warning.

move the tsconfig.json to src folder from root