# "ng serve" throws 'Module build failed:' error

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-cli

I am receiving an error when trying to use the **serve** command in Angular-CLI.
The error I am receiving is this:

[image]

I tried to resolve these @types\jasmine\index.d issue by following the suggestions here : [ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules\@types\jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181156/error-in-at-loader-node-modules-types-jasmine/42182400#42182400) , however the typescript version that I pinned in the package.json file is "2.1.6" in order to alleviate other issues I was experiencing in the past. Any suggestions?

Comment: check that image link.

Comment: What image link? The one that is of my cmd?

Comment: Thanks Tim Consolazio for your comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng serve throwing errors with simple ng new angular cli project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595263/ng-serve-throwing-errors-with-simple-ng-new-angular-cli-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My webpack compiled successfully by making sure that the package.json file contained:

```
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.41"
"typescript": "^2.0.0"
```

After executing "npm install", everything worked.

Comment: Your fix will work (because jasmine typings were updated) however the underlying cause is most likely because your angular-cli version is out of date. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595263/ng-serve-throwing-errors-with-simple-ng-new-angular-cli-project/42607000