# ng serve throwing errors with simple ng new angular cli project

Tags: angular, webpack, jasmine, angular-cli

I am new to a `angular-cli` and have created an angular 2 project with `ng new angular2` command. Now when I try to run it with `ng serve`, it just crashes with some errors.

**Log:**

```
ERROR in [default] C:\Users\user\desktop\angularcli\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:39:37
A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\user\desktop\angularcli\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:39:45
Cannot find name 'keyof'.

ERROR in [default] C:\Users\user\desktop\angularcli\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:39:51
'=' expected.
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset     Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
    index.html  2.81 kB       0
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

I don't know why I get this trace as I haven't made any changes in the files.
Does anyone know why this error occurs or someone might have encountered it before.

Sharing the config that I get on running `ng --version`-

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.18
node: 6.9.5
os: win32 x64
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Do you have an update version of the angular cli? What does `ng --version` give you?

Comment: can u share the screenshot of the error and the version of **angular-cli**

Comment: Updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: The beta version might not work, update the version.

Comment: and why is it so that it won't work@RomanC

Comment: One of the problems is that type definitions for Jasmine was updated for TypeScript 2.1, but you version of CLI uses TypeScript 2.0. Just do as Roman suggests - update CLI and get back if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok @YaroslavAdmin. I will try and get back if the problem persists.

Comment: I updated it to `@angular/cli` and it worked. However I get some errors on running `ng new projectname` and I am opening a new thread for it. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem, you are still using the beta version of angular cli - they have now have an RC version. Upgrading will fix your issue. Also worth noting that the project has moved in NPM it is now `@angular/cli` instead of `angular-cli`.

[This page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-rc-update) will show you how to upgrade - it gives instructions on how to upgrade globally and also how to upgrade individual projects (you will need to do both).

Note: Not essential but it will also give you warnings if you aren't running Node 6.9 +

Comment: I already updated the version if you read the comments above. Thanks anyways. +1